# How to keep leading/prefix zeros when export to Excel/csv by SQL query statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I use Oracle and I would like to know how to keep leading/prefix zeros when export to Excel/csv by below SQL query statement?

Supposed `B.h`（string type） maybe have the values of 00068573 and 098235

```
SELECT A.e,
       A.f,
       A.g,
       B.h
FROM A 
JOIN C ON C.e=A.e
JOIN B ON C.j=B.j;
```

and I export data in Python, partial code as below:

```
for row_data in cursor:
    output.writerow(row_data)
```

Thank you so much for any advice.

Comment: What is the type of the `B.h` column? If it's a string type (e.g. VARCHAR2), it should work out of the box. If it's a numeric type (e.g. NUMBER), you'll have to provide an explicit format mask, since leading zeroes aren't stored for numeric types.

Comment: `B.h` is a string type

Comment: If it's stored as a string in the database, exporting the data will keep the leading zeroes (unless your host language performs some kind of conversion / truncation). Please [edit] the question and add the code in your host language (e.g. Python) that you use to export the data.

Comment: hi, yes, I export data in Python, partial code as below:`for row_data in cursor:
    output.writerow(row_data)` I already updated my question, thank you so much

Comment: That's much better, but could you please [edit] your question once more and add the complete Python code to turn this into a [MCVE] ? That would be terrific :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set heading off
set termout OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TAB OFF
set pause off
set verify off
SET UNDERLINE OFF
set trimspool on
set timing off
set echo off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
COLUMN CODE2 FORMAT 09999999
SET COLSEP ';'
spool test.csv

SELECT A.e,
       A.f,
       A.g,
       B.h as code2
FROM A 
JOIN C ON C.e=A.e
JOIN B ON C.j=B.j; 
spool off
exit;
```

or use     `to_char(B.h, '09999999')`

```
set heading off
    set termout OFF
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET TAB OFF
    set pause off
    set verify off
    SET UNDERLINE OFF
    set trimspool on
    set timing off
    set echo off
    set linesize 1000
    set pagesize 0
    SET COLSEP ';'
    spool test.csv

    SELECT A.e,
           A.f,
           A.g,
           to_char(B.h, '09999999')
    FROM A 
    JOIN C ON C.e=A.e
    JOIN B ON C.j=B.j; 
    spool off
    exit;
```

if the field is character then you need to use the lpad function.

```
 SELECT A.e,
           A.f,
           A.g,
           LPAD(B.h, 9, '0') 
    FROM A 
    JOIN C ON C.e=A.e
    JOIN B ON C.j=B.j;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your detailed answer, I use python to save data to [.csv], I got a error of `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number` when execute `for row_data in cursor:
 output.writerow(row_data)`, do you know the reason? Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: hey, the `B.h` is a string type, is that the reason why I got that error? I noticed `09999999` is the placeholder with specified number, but my leading zeros are maybe like three zeros `00068573 or one zero `098235`

Comment: if the `b.h`  is character then you need to use the `lpad` function.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, unfortunately it didn't work, leading zeros were still removed.  I export the data in Python, partial code as below:`for row_data in cursor: output.writerow(row_data)`, is that the reason why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You must have done export in csv format. From the Oracle export you will get actual value including leading zero. Open the .csv file in the text editor and check the values. There is nothing to do with sql if you are getting export by using any of IDE (i.e. SQL developer)

Answer (score 0):

Above said is Absolutely right, will add:-

- opening csv by double clicking opens it in excel which won't show trailing zeroes.
- You can open in text to confirm that you will have zeroes.
- Now to use in excel, simply open a new excel >> Go to "Data" TAB >> "GET DATA">> From a File  and choose csv/txt. This way it will load properly without removing trailing zeroes also you will have some options like changing encoding.